# Local fields vs. self-Pontryagin-dual locally compact fields with self-dual Schwartz-Bruhat functional

Tags: number-theory, local-field

The local fields $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and the Adele ring $\mathbb{A}$ are all Pontrjagin dual to themselves (self duality). The consideration of the multiplicative Fourier transform of additive characters and Schwartz-Bruhat functionals $f$ with $f = \hat{f}$ (I also call this self duality) both give interesting functions.

I am thinking about which locally compact rings are Pontrjagin dual to themselves. I was hoping that there was a close relationship between self duality for locally compact rings and Adele rings.

First I want to show the connection in the "local" case: a relationship between local fields and locally compact fields with self duality. Then I would like to extend the connection to a relationship between locally compact rings with self duality and Adele rings.

Here is what I want to know:

- Can you construct all self dual locally compact fields with a self dual Schwartz-Bruhat functional using local fields and simple operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the requirement to be self-dual. What are the locally compact fields, i.e., fields with a locally compact Hausdorff topology making the field operations continuous?

Every field becomes a locally compact field when you give it the discrete topology. That is uninteresting.  All other examples (locally compact fields with a non-discrete topology) turn out to be the finite extension fields of $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf Q_p$, or a Laurent series field $\mathbf F_p((t))$ for some prime $p$. And all of these are self-dual in the sense of Pontryagin duality.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, and I didn't think to show this. I can't prove it on my own because I don't have this matroid lemma https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455112/establishing-a-matroid-for-higher-local-fields-k-lt₁-tₙ . Maybe one of your packets has a similar theorem. Do you know a link to this theorem?

Comment: (The matroid lemma + locally compact gives that only Laurent series can be used)

Comment: I would like to add that, while I am perfectly satisfied with this as an answer, I didn't necessarily gain any insight into the prevalence of self dual Schwartz-Bruhat functionals or their analogues for the higher local fields.

Comment: I might like to also see if you know anything about theorems in the way of "all XYZ topological fields are completions of algebraic extensions of n-tuple Laurent series over a local field or finite field".

Comment: The Laurent series rings are locally σ-compact, maybe the theorem extends.

Comment: I don't know such a link.